# Is Civ V as moddable as Civ IV?

Tags: modding

Civilization IV was a highly moddable game, and many great mods/games were built off it <sub>([Fall From Heaven 2](http://kael.civfanatics.net/About.shtml) being my personal favorite)</sub>.

Does Civilization V have the same opportunities for modding that Civilization IV offered?

Comment: Shouldn't this question be moved to http://gaming.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @jpbochi According to [your meta](http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/58/do-mod-and-map-making-questions-belong-here/59#59) it belongs here.  Questions about how to play a mod go on [Gaming](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @CRoss - while that may be the case (and I feel only a subset of questions related to modding are really appropriate here), gaming is where you would have an audience that may be able to answer your question.

Comment: Actually creating mods is more related to game developement than to gaming in general.

Comment: @dash I'll tell you right now this question will get closed to gaming.  It specifically [prohibits](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/544/do-map-editor-questions-belong-here/545#545 "maps") [discussion](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/562/do-mod-development-questions-belong-here/566#566 "mods") on the creation of mods.  For reference on [what is allowed](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1130/are-questions-about-prominent-mods-on-topic "spoiler: questions about play") on gaming

Comment: This question does not seem to ask about creating mods, but about whether or not they are enabled by the software.  The OP does not specify if he intends to create a mod or just desires to one day download one.  I would find it hard to believe that they would prohibit discussion of mods from a player's perspective.

Comment: @dash the question could be asked in a manner that's on-topic for either community TBQH. "What tools are available to mod Civilization V" would make more sense here. "Are there any/will there be any mods for Civilization V" would fit in more at Gaming.SE. While this question as phrased is admittedly, slightly ambiguous between those two.

Comment: @LessPop- given the OP's reference of what I presume to be someone else's mod, it seems *to me* to be from a player's perspective rather than a developer's.

Comment: @dash-tom-bang, I think it's kind of unimportant what perspective the question was written from, while more important what the question actually asks. As a game developer I want to know the answer to this question, and so I think it's perfectly suited for right here.

Comment: "Does game X have feature Y?"

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz good point, I think you're right. Still, even what @ZorbaTHut said makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

As I recall, Firaxis has discussed plans to release an SDK for Civ V (as they did with Civ IV), but I do not believe they have released one *yet*.  If and when the SDK is released, you will be able to mod Civ V like there's no tomorrow.

You can be reasonably sure this will happen--mods are a big deal in Civ V, and the game even has a built-in mod browser.

Comment: The SDK is released, and is available through Steam.